# Swagger codegen error NoSuchMethodError:hasExplicitTimeZone() after version updated

Tags: maven, jackson, swagger-codegen

I decided to update version of io.swagger.codegen.v3 to newest (3.0.26) , but it throws error.

From where that error could be appeared?

```
Failed to execute goal io.swagger.codegen.v3:swagger-codegen-maven-plugin:3.0.26:generate (convert) on project home-open-api: Execution convert of goal io.swagger.codegen.v3:swagger-codegen-maven-plugin:3.0.26:generate failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing io.swagger.codegen.v3:swagger-codegen-maven-plugin:3.0.26:generate: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationConfig.hasExplicitTimeZone()'
```

Then it shows a lot of jars. Have no idea why they appeared and how to react

```
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>io.swagger.codegen.v3:swagger-codegen-maven-plugin:3.0.26
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/io/swagger/codegen/v3/swagger-codegen-maven-plugin/3.0.26/swagger-codegen-maven-plugin-3.0.26.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/aether/aether-util/1.0.0.v20140518/aether-util-1.0.0.v20140518.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/javax/enterprise/cdi-api/1.0/cdi-api-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/sisu/org.eclipse.sisu.inject/0.3.0.M1/org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.3.0.M1.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/3.2.3/sisu-guice-3.2.3-no_aop.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.21/plexus-interpolation-1.21.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.20/plexus-utils-3.0.20.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/3.4/maven-plugin-annotations-3.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/io/swagger/codegen/v3/swagger-codegen/3.0.26/swagger-codegen-3.0.26.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/io/swagger/swagger-parser/1.0.55/swagger-parser-1.0.55.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/io/swagger/swagger-core/1.6.2/swagger-core-1.6.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.11.4/jackson-annotations-2.11.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.11.4/jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.11.4/jackson-core-2.11.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/jackson-dataformat-yaml/2.11.4/jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.11.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.24/snakeyaml-1.24.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/io/swagger/swagger-models/1.6.2/swagger-models-1.6.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[21] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/io/swagger/swagger-annotations/1.6.2/swagger-annotations-1.6.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[22] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[23] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/io/swagger/parser/v3/swagger-parser/2.0.26/swagger-parser-2.0.26.jar
[ERROR] urls[24] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/io/swagger/parser/v3/swagger-parser-v2-converter/2.0.26/swagger-parser-v2-converter-2.0.26.jar
[ERROR] urls[25] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/io/swagger/core/v3/swagger-models/2.1.9/swagger-models-2.1.9.jar
[ERROR] urls[26] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/io/swagger/parser/v3/swagger-parser-core/2.0.26/swagger-parser-core-2.0.26.jar
[ERROR] urls[27] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/io/swagger/parser/v3/swagger-parser-v3/2.0.26/swagger-parser-v3-2.0.26.jar
[ERROR] urls[28] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/io/swagger/core/v3/swagger-core/2.1.9/swagger-core-2.1.9.jar
[ERROR] urls[29] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/jakarta/xml/bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api/2.3.2/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[30] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/jakarta/activation/jakarta.activation-api/1.2.1/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[31] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.12.1/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.12.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[32] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/io/swagger/core/v3/swagger-annotations/2.1.9/swagger-annotations-2.1.9.jar
[ERROR] urls[33] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/jakarta/validation/jakarta.validation-api/2.0.2/jakarta.validation-api-2.0.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[34] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/io/swagger/swagger-codegen/2.4.20/swagger-codegen-2.4.20.jar
[ERROR] urls[35] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/io/swagger/swagger-compat-spec-parser/1.0.55/swagger-compat-spec-parser-1.0.55.jar
[ERROR] urls[36] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/com/github/java-json-tools/json-schema-validator/2.2.14/json-schema-validator-2.2.14.jar
[ERROR] urls[37] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/com/github/java-json-tools/jackson-coreutils-equivalence/1.0/jackson-coreutils-equivalence-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[38] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/com/github/java-json-tools/json-schema-core/1.2.14/json-schema-core-1.2.14.jar
[ERROR] urls[39] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/com/github/java-json-tools/uri-template/0.10/uri-template-0.10.jar
[ERROR] urls[40] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/org/mozilla/rhino/1.7.7.2/rhino-1.7.7.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[41] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/com/sun/mail/mailapi/1.6.2/mailapi-1.6.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[42] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/joda-time/joda-time/2.10.5/joda-time-2.10.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[43] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/com/googlecode/libphonenumber/libphonenumber/8.11.1/libphonenumber-8.11.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[44] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/net/sf/jopt-simple/jopt-simple/5.0.4/jopt-simple-5.0.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[45] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/com/github/java-json-tools/json-patch/1.13/json-patch-1.13.jar
[ERROR] urls[46] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/com/github/java-json-tools/msg-simple/1.2/msg-simple-1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[47] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/com/github/java-json-tools/btf/1.3/btf-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[48] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/com/github/java-json-tools/jackson-coreutils/2.0/jackson-coreutils-2.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[49] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.2/httpclient-4.5.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[50] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.4/httpcore-4.4.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[51] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[52] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.9/commons-codec-1.9.jar
[ERROR] urls[53] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/com/samskivert/jmustache/1.12/jmustache-1.12.jar
[ERROR] urls[54] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[55] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-ext/1.7.25/slf4j-ext-1.7.25.jar
[ERROR] urls[56] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[57] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.2.3/logback-core-1.2.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[58] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.4/commons-lang3-3.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[59] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.2/commons-cli-1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[60] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/23.0/guava-23.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[61] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.jar
[ERROR] urls[62] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.0.18/error_prone_annotations-2.0.18.jar
[ERROR] urls[63] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/com/google/j2objc/j2objc-annotations/1.1/j2objc-annotations-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[64] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/mojo/animal-sniffer-annotations/1.14/animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar
[ERROR] urls[65] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/com/github/jknack/handlebars/4.1.2/handlebars-4.1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[66] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/com/atlassian/commonmark/commonmark/0.9.0/commonmark-0.9.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[67] = file:/C:/Users/1/.m2/repository/io/swagger/codegen/v3/swagger-codegen-generators/1.0.26/swagger-codegen-generators-1.0.26.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
```

First idea was something gone wrong with compatibility of dependencies, but I tried to change version of dependecies and that did not help, only log with versions changed